# How to start a django project on one that is already created?

Tags: django, linux

I already have a django project and all files created, but I am trying to deploy to a server. I moved files over to server using FileZilla and I am in putty now trying to `django-admin startproject practice ~/practice` but I get a command error stating that this already exists which obviously it does but then if I want to `manage.py makemigrations` I get a `-bash: Permission denied` and I am guessing that is because I have not started django project here on putty??? I hope there is enough info here to explain my issue. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need run python manage.py runserver in the correct folder with admin permisions.